# assigning new word by creating a new column when finding match

Tags: python, pandas, matching

I have a survey df and I want to assign a new value of either "existing customer" 
or "new customer based" on their answers. if someone for instance has 3 answers but one of 
them matches "coca cola" I want to give them the value of existing customer 
here is the data frame:

```
 ID       Question                                                Answer
101005   what brands did you purchase the past 5 months   Coca-Cola or Pepsi or vitamin water
026458   what brands did you purchase the past 5 months           None
045987   what brands  did you purchase the past 5 months        Coca-Cola
```

Here is the table I would like to have

```
ID        Question                                          Answer                      Buyer_Type

101005   what brands did you purchase the past 5 months  Coca-Cola,Pepsi,fanta          Existing Users          
026458   what brands did you purchase the past 5 months  None                           New Buyer              
045987   what brands did you purchase the past 5 months  Coca-Cola                      Existing Users
```

I tried this code but for some reason it shows for instance 101005 as new buyer even though this id say they had purchase coca cola in the past:

```
deux['Buyer_Type'] = deux['answer'].apply(lambda x:'existing buyer' if x == 'Coca-Cola' else 'new buyer')
```

For some reasons it is not recognizing 101005 as an existing users

Comment: `df['Buyer_Type'] = np.where(df.Answer.str.contains('Coca-Cola'), 'Existing Users', 'New Buyer')`?

Comment: Just for the sake if improving the answer a tiny bit, might want to lower everything or make it a bit more flexible (case = False).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementing a bit to @Quang Hoang's comment, adding `case=False` and a two condition for `coca` and `cola` will help the solution be more flexible for different type of values in the `Answer` column as shown in the example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4],'Answer':['Coca-Cola',None,'coca-cola','cocaCola']})
df['Buyer_Type'] = np.where(df['Answer'].str.contains('coca',case=False) & df['Answer'].str.contains('cola',case=False),
                            "Existing user","New buyer")
```

Output:

```
   ID     Answer     Buyer_Type
0   1  Coca-Cola  Existing user
1   2       None      New buyer
2   3  coca-cola  Existing user
3   4   cocaCola  Existing user
```